# @PowerMockIgnore gets ignored by Gradle

Tags: gradle, mocking

When I run my tests in Intellij they pass. But if I run them on command-line "gradle build" they fail. Does gradle pickup the @PowerMockIgnore annotation? Because it seems like it misses it on command-line. Thanks